# Return Result of Subscription in if / else

Tags: angular, observable

I have a function that should return a boolean, based on the return value of a function that makes a http post request:

```js
    checkPost(callRequest: boolean): boolean {
        console.log('START REQUEST');
        if(callRequest){
            this.makeRequest().subscribe(result => {
                console.log(`RESULT ${result}`);
                return result;
            }
            console.log('THIS SHOULD NEVER SHOW');
        }else{
            ...
        }
        console.log('THIS SHOULD ALSO NEVER SHOW');
    }
```

The `makeRequest` is fairly simple:

```js
    makeRequest(): Observable<boolean> {
        ...other stuff...
        return this.http.post<UserData>(oauth2_token_endpoint, body, {headers})
            .pipe(map(user => {
              if (user && user.access_token) {
                this._saveToken(user);
                this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                return true;
              }
              return false;
            }));
    }
```

The post may take 1-5 seconds, which is fine, but I want to make sure, that the `checkPost()` returns the result of the `makeRequest()` (waits for it). It should never be possible to get beyond the `if / else`, what would be the corrrect approach?

I tried:

```js
    this.makeRequest().pipe(map(result => {
        console.log(`RESULT: ${result}`);
        return result;
    }));
```

but this does not trigger the request after all.

Angular 8.2.14

Answer (score 1):

In general is a very bad idea to have a function that return true or false after call a request. you can has a function that return an observable of boolean (or observable of any), then you subscribe.

```
checkPost(callRequest: boolean): Observable<any> {
   if (callRequest)  //if callRequest, return the response of this.makeRequest
      return this.makeRequest();

   return of(null);  //else return "null" -case 1-
}
```

And you subscribe to checkPost as usually

```
this.myservice.checkPost(true).subscribe(res=>{
  if (res==null)
        ....fall in case 1..
  if (res==true)
      ....
  if (res==false)
     ...console.res
})
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you could try something like that (not sure if this work properly but you get the idea)

```js
    async checkPost(callRequest: boolean): boolean {
        console.log('START REQUEST');
        if (callRequest){
            return await this.makeRequest().subscribe(result => {
                console.log(`RESULT ${result}`);
                return result;
            }
            console.log('THIS SHOULD NEVER SHOW');
        }else{
            ...
        }
        console.log('THIS SHOULD ALSO NEVER SHOW');
    }
```

Comment: This is bad advice since a subscription should not be handled like a promise.

Comment: So please, suggest something relevant @LingVu

Comment: Don't take it personally.

Comment: Just marked that this is not a solution that should be used. Why? Because it is just bad coding. There is already a good solution how observables should be used. So just take notes from it or not. I will not continue this meaningless discussion.